# Qt5 - How to specify some draggable areas in a frameless window?

Tags: c++, qt

I made a frameless window in Qt5. Now, I need to specify some draggable areas (QFrame) to move the window. If I define mouseMoveEvent() and mousePressEvent() just like in the clock example, the window becomes fully draggable...

```
void MainWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        move(event->globalPos() - dragPos);
        event->accept();
    }
}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        dragPos = event->globalPos() - frameGeometry().topLeft();
        event->accept();
    }
}
```

Should I create a QFrame subclass with mouseMoveEvent() and mousePressEvent()?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use event filter, in this case this task can be done without subclassing:

```
QPoint dragPos;//somewhere
//...
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{

    if (obj == ui->frame && event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        QMouseEvent *ev = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
        if (ev->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
        {

            dragPos = ev->globalPos() - ui->frame->geometry().topLeft();
        }
    }
    if (obj == ui->frame && event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        QMouseEvent *ev = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
        if (ev->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
        {
            ui->frame->move(ev->globalPos() - dragPos);
        }
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

To use `eventFilter` you should also:

```
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);//in header
```

and

```
qApp->installEventFilter(this);//in constructor
```

With this code I can easily drag my `ui->frame`

Comment: Ok, so do I have to remove the mouseMoveEvent() and mousePressEvent() definitions? I tried to insert your code and the window doesn't move at all..

Comment: @Helen90 yes, remove, you need only filter. Also make sure that you use suitable frame, my frame name and your frame name can be different.

Comment: Yes, I changed the name to "myFrame". Is it the same if the frame is inside another widget (MainWindow -> otherWidget -> myFrame)? 
In the constructor I've written: 

ui->setupUi(this);
this->installEventFilter(this);

Comment: @Helen90 In mainwindow all widgets contains in centralWidget so it is not a problem, add qDebug()<<"it works"; inside `if` to see is your filter work(print something to see is your filter was installed correctly).

Comment: @Helen90 I'm struck that so many people don't listen to me, many other peoples set `this->installEventFilter(this);` too but in my answer I wrote very clear: should be `qApp->installEventFilter(this);`

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry.. I was wrong to install the filter.. Now it works, but only for that frame. I would like to move the entire window through the frame instead. (Thanks for your time :-) )

Comment: @Helen90 You can do similar things for all QWidget subclass(all objects which has move() method), frame, label, or whole mainwindow, does not matter